# Is it possible to build a self-contained library with gcc (i.e., one which statically incorporates its dependencies)?

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw, static-libraries

I'm trying to build a library with gcc (actually, MinGW) which depends on stdlibc++. I want to build mylib such that all of its dependencies get incorporated into it, so that anyone linking with mylib doesn't need to link against stdlibc++ (or, if they do, it's because their own code depends on stdlibc++). Can this be done?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do that, is that the only solution? Shipping a statically compiled version of your local standard library is a bad idea.

Comment: Have you verified that you can build a library with GCC and have that link against code compiled with Borland's compiler, at all? As far as I know, there's no guarantee that C compilers share the same library format ... Unless this is a DLL and/or dynamic/shared library of course.

Comment: You have both C and C++ listed. Which language are you using? Do you know which version of Borland compiler your user is using? Does it link against msvcrt? There are many things that could make this not work.

Comment: stdlib from mingw and stdlib for borland can conflict.

Comment: @birryee: I list both C and C++ because the library exposes a C API for some C++ code. I don't know the version of the Borland compiler being used. It's actually libstdc++ which we'd like to swallow, not stdlib; I've edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: Sounds like this is your proposed solution to a problem. Can you ask about the original problem instead? I doubt this is the best solution...

Comment: @tenfour: Our library depends on libstdc++. Our user is building with an old Borland compiler, so can't link against .a files. We'd like to build with MinGW ourselves, and we don't want to ship a DLL.

Comment: Question not answered: *Why* don't you want to ship a DLL?

Comment: @DevSolar: The user is going to be statically linking against our library, so we can't ship a DLL.

Comment: @Tenfour, the problem was described in a prior version of the question: The intended consumer of Uckelman's library is a Borland linker that apparently con't consume libstdc++.a (which is really no surprise since Borland provides its own standard-library implementation). Uckelman wants to remove his library's dependency on libstdc++ by incorporating the necessary parts of that library into his own.

Comment: @Santiago: "Shipping a statically compiled version of your local standard library is a bad idea." I believe just the opposite. Have you any reasons for this statement? It will eliminate the possibility of in the field failures due to dll's with the wrong version/missing/configuration issues. It runs faster and has a smaller executable.

Comment: @Jay: Erm... wrong? It will *not* run faster (and why should it?). It will *definitely* result in a larger executable, because it will not refer to a *dynamically* linked, *shared* library, but will contain any used library code *statically* linked into the executable. Even a trivial program using `<string>`, `<vector>` and `<iostream>` adds ~ 1.3 MByte to the executable if linked statically. Oh, and that amount of memory is used up for *every* instance of the executable being run, instead of multiple instances *sharing* the DLL.

Comment: @uckelman: OK, so the question not answered is: Why does *the customer* not want to link against a DLL? Supporting old development environments goes only so far. At some point, you *have* to update, because the effort to update is less than the effort to still support the old crap...

Comment: @DevSolar: The customer doesn't want a DLL for exactly the reason mentioned above, namely the wrong version/missing/configuration issues. What I'm trying to determine by this question is how much effort it will be to support the old crap.

Comment: The problems your client has with a DLL are nothing special; it should be easy to satisfy them with the old "that's how literally every other app works, and they work" argument. You are trying to create a barrier between runtimes (for good reason), and a DLL is a very good way of doing that. With a static lib, you will be more prone to hidden errors / heap corruption / conflicts in runtime details. If I was in your shoes, I'd fight for DLL as it's a cleaner solution and if you are dealing with old Borland compilers, you want to make that barrier as strong as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ar -x` to extract the *.o* files you need from the original library (*libstdc++*, in your case). Include those *.o* files with your own when you link your library. Make sure the distribution terms of the original library are compatible with those of your own.

Comment: Shouldn't it be enough to include the library itself in the command line? AFAIK, the compiler is smart enough to extract the object files from a `*.a` file by itself.